# CAP_NET_ADMIN causes SSL to break in rust binary

Tags: ssl, rust, root, linux-capabilities, reqwest

I am working on a rust networking application. And I download a package from gcloud storage (using an https://... URL). I will eventually need the capabilities CAP_NET_ADMIN and CAP_NET_RAW.

This is my rust program:

```
pub fn download_runner_binary(bin_dir: PathBuf) -> Result<()> {

    let uri = "https://example.com/foo.tar";

    let response = reqwest::blocking::get(uri)?;

    let tar_path = bin_dir.join("foo.tar");
    let tar_path2 = tar_path.clone();

    let mut dest = File::create(tar_path)?;

    io::copy(&mut Cursor::new(&mut response.bytes()?), &mut dest)?;

    // now seek the beginning
    let dest_f = File::open(tar_path2)?;

    // now extract the files here
    let mut archive = Archive::new(dest_f);
    archive.unpack(bin_dir)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

It compiles fine, and I can run it just fine. Subsequently I do:

`sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' ./target/debug/foo`

and when I `getcap`:

```
getcap ./target/debug/foo
./target/debug/foo = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip
```

At this stage, when I run my program:

```
(base) ➜  wallet git:(s/permissions) ✗ ./target/debug/foo init
Initializing job runner
Error: NetworkError: `error sending request for url (https://example.com/): error trying to connect: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914: (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

Caused by:
    0: error sending request for url (https://example.com/foo.tar): error trying to connect: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914: (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    1: error trying to connect: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914: (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    2: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914: (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    3: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914:
```

And I can't pull things down from any SSL url. Once I remove these capabilities with `setcap -r ./target/debug/foo`, it is all good.

I then wrote a small python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://example.com/foo.tar')

print(resp.text)
```

Setting the same capabilities on this script and running `./test.py` completes with no issues.

Is reqwest doing something weird? Is there some issue with certificates? Is it some issue with my local SSL setup?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe setting the capabilities on the python script doesn't do anything, you would need to set the capabilities on the interpreter (e.g. the `python` executable) for them to be used.

Comment: The `setcap` man page states that: _"setting an empty capability set is not the same as removing it."_ I believe that by setting any capability explicitly you have also removed some implicit capabilities that are required for SSL to work. Removing all capabilities with `setcap -r` reinstates the default capabilities.

Comment: So if I switch to a pure-rust SSL (using rustls), it is all good. SoI guess @Jmb is right - setting those capabilities does nuke some ssl capabilities. The whole thing is quite poorly documented.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this on an Arch Linux and couldn't (it would just work, setcap or not). I wonder what other conditions there are.

Comment: So it looks like this is unique to my setup (vanilla ubuntu 20.04) - I guess I can avoid using the native os SSL stack from rust for a bit (though I guess it is hard to completely avoid the stack)

Comment: What does `getpcaps $$` say? Are you running with some Ambient capabilities? If you have something other than `=`, your environment may be relying on this unusual default in some way. Using a file capability of any sort will completely override the Ambient ones.

Comment: Was empty before I ran setcap on it.

Comment: Does it work if you give it _all_ capabilities? Does your binary use some non-standard shared library, what does `ldd your_program` say?